# Android databinding <include> tag binding with viewModel is not working

Tags: android, android-databinding

I want to include a custom xml layout in my main layout, and bind a custom viewModel with custom xml, but it not working, The value in viewModel is not appear in xml. There is my codes:
Main.xml:

```
<layout>

<data>

    <import type="com.example.databindingpractise.upDownchoiceWidget.UpDownChoiceViewModel"/>
    <variable
        name="upDownviewModel"
        type="UpDownChoiceViewModel"/>
</data>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/upanddown"
        app:upDownviewModel="@{upDownviewModel}"
        layout="@layout/up_and_down_choice_layout"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

up_and_down_choice_layout.xml:

```
<layout >

<data>

    <import type="com.example.databindingpractise.upDownchoiceWidget.UpDownChoiceViewModel"/>

    <variable
        name="upDownviewModel"
        type="UpDownChoiceViewModel"/>
</data>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/order_around_shadow">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:text="@{upDownviewModel.upLocation}"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dataBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    UpAndDownChoiceLayoutBinding upAndDownChoiceLayoutBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.up_and_down_choice_layout, null, false);

    UpDownChoiceViewModel upDownChoiceViewModel = new UpDownChoiceViewModel();
    upAndDownChoiceLayoutBinding.setUpDownviewModel(upDownChoiceViewModel);

}
```

How to binding the `upDownChoiceViewModel` with `up_and_down_choice_layout.xml`, Could anyone solve my question？

Answer (score 0):

Use like below.

```
<data>       

    <variable
        name="upDownviewModel"
        type="com.example.databindingpractise.upDownchoiceWidget.UpDownChoiceViewModel" />
</data>
```

Comment: Thank you for response，but it is not working as well.

Comment: I have found the solution. `upAndDownChoiceLayoutBinding.setUpDownviewModel(upDownChoiceViewModel);` is not working. Databinding must be set in parent view like this: `dataBinding.setVariable(BR.upDownviewModel, upDownChoiceViewModel);`, and pass the viewModel object by ‘bind’ attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this

```
    <layout>

<data>

    <variable
        name="upDownviewModel"
        type="com.example.databindingpractise.upDownchoiceWidget.UpDownChoiceViewModel"/>
</data>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/upanddown"
        app:upDownviewModel="@{upDownviewModel}"
        layout="@layout/up_and_down_choice_layout"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

up_and_down_choice_layout

```
<layout >

<data>

    <variable
        name="upDownviewModel"
        type="com.example.databindingpractise.upDownchoiceWidget.UpDownChoiceViewModel"/>
</data>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/order_around_shadow">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:text="@{upDownviewModel.upLocation}"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for response，but it is not working as well. Is there anything wrong in my defined code?

Comment: I have found the solution. `upAndDownChoiceLayoutBinding.setUpDownviewModel(upDownChoiceViewModel);` is not working. Databinding must be set in parent view like this: `dataBinding.setVariable(BR.upDownviewModel, upDownChoiceViewModel);`, and pass the viewModel object by ‘bind’ attribute.